# Eclipse IDE Code formatting: turning off indentation

Tags: java, eclipse, formatter

I like being able to use the (Java) Code Formatter in Eclipse, but Eclipse reformats this:

```
return new Element( OrderXMLGeneratorConstants.PERSONAL_DETAILS )
    .addContent( createElement( OrderXMLGeneratorConstants.FIRST_NAME, firstName ) )
    .addContent( createElement( OrderXMLGeneratorConstants.LAST_NAME, lastName ) )
    .addContent( createElement( OrderXMLGeneratorConstants.EMAIL, email ) );
```

to

```
return new Element( OrderXMLGeneratorConstants.PERSONAL_DETAILS )
                                                                   .addContent( createElement( OrderXMLGeneratorConstants.FIRST_NAME, firstName ) )
                                                                   .addContent( createElement( OrderXMLGeneratorConstants.LAST_NAME, lastName ) )   
                                                                   .addContent( createElement( OrderXMLGeneratorConstants.EMAIL, email ) )
```

How can I use the Code Formatter without getting this ridiculous amount of indentation?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to `Windows` -> `Preferences` :

In the dialog, select `Java` -> `Code Style` -> `Formatter` and select `Edit`.

Under the `line wrapping` tab, `Function Calls` -> `Qualified invocations`, you select `indent by one`, or `Default Indentation` at the bottom drop down menu (Indentation policy)

This one is probably set to `Indent on column`... this is what you do NOT want.

Edit and note : I use Helios SR1. I think the options are the same on Ganymede or Galileo though.

Comment: Thank you thank you thank you. I was changing the wrapping policy (and in fact turning it off), not the indentation policy.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to modify the formatter settings. Go to `window`->`preferences`->`java`->`code style`->`formatter`. I think you need to look at the indentation policy on the `line wrapping` tab.